# Lowercase methods with the same name as the class recognized as constructor

Tags: php, constructor, php-5.5

Using PHP 5.5. I'm having the following problem:

```
class Foo {
    function __construct() {
    }

    function foo($bar) {
    }
}
```

There is a valid constructor and my method foo() is lowercase. If i create an object with

```
$f = new Foo();
```

I get a warning like

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for Foo::foo()
```

So PHP interprets the method foo() as a second constructor. Is there a PHP setting to stop this behavior?

Thank you

Chris

Comment: I can't reproduce this on PHP 5.x only 4 - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/be8f505719ffe110a505d8be3e3e63b4e051a04d

Comment: Sure __construct will be executed but the warning is not nice

Comment: Only the `__construct` is called in 5.x.

Answer (score 2):

User-defined PHP functions are case-insensitive.  :-(

Comment: @JohnKiller Imagine newbies creating $Foo, $fOo, $foO, $FOO, etc.  It's inconsistent with the rest of PHP, and it prevents people who know what they're doing from distinguishing by case.

Comment: @JohnKiller I disagree, but this isn't chat.  :-)

Comment: in this case for me it's a bad thing but not a problem at all